# Animate linear-gradient compatible with all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to do a "linear-gradient" animation wich is compatible with all browsers but no luck.

first i try using css

```
.anim {
    animate: anim 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes anim {
    0%, 100% {background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(X,X,X,0.8) 0%, rgba(X,X,X,0) 100%);}
    30% {background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(X,X,X,0.8) 0%, rgba(X,X,X,0) 100%);}
    70% {background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(X,X,X,0.8) 0%, rgba(X,X,X,0) 100%);}
}
```

but this code only work for browsers like chrome, safari, edge... but not on firefox.

I read on some forums that this type of animations not work for firefox, the i try with jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function Anim(){
        $('.anim').animate({
            background:'linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(X,X,X,0.8) 0%, rgba(X,X,X,0) 100%)'
        }, 1500)
        .animte({
            background:'linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(X,X,X,0.8) 0%, rgba(X,X,X,0) 100%)'
        }, 1500)
        .animate({
            background:'linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(X,X,X,0.8) 0%, rgba(X,X,X,0) 100%)'
        }, 1500, Anim);
    }

    Anim();
});
```

But no luck, this one not working anywhere.

PS: I try as well using "-moz-linear-gradient" or "-webkit-linear-gradient"

Comment: Please define *all* browsers. I am sure IE6 still exists on some systems. So what is the support matrix of browsers you are trying to support?

Comment: Perhaps not with CSS, however you could do it with Javascript via requestAnimationFrame, such as done by Velocity.js

Comment: Should note though that all of your keyframe values are identical, meaning there would be no change, assuming all *X* values are the same

Comment: This might be helpful: https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/animating-css-gradients-using-only-css-d2fd7671e759#.6uul2jr4p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Full support fixed

base on your website I'm figure it out. You don't need to use `linear-gradient`, just add one more selector and change your all animation base on `box-shadow`.

---

**For example:**

Add `:before` selector and set full size (like the parent - `.header`). Your all animation calling insert to this selector to. Don't forget to `top:-100%;` for top shadowing start and `z-index: -1;` that set the `:before` content under the `.header` content.

```
.header:before {
    z-index: -1;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: hac 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: hac 4s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: hac 4s linear infinite;
}
```

**box-shadow animation example:**

`blur-radius` should be `50px` like the parent height (`.header`)

```
0%, 100% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(255,81,93,0.8) }
30% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(39,175,131,0.8) }
70% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(199,130,207,0.8) }
```

---

**And all together:**

```css
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.header:before {
    z-index: -1;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: hac 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: hac 4s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: hac 4s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes hac {
    0%, 100% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(255,81,93,0.8) }
    30% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(39,175,131,0.8) }
    70% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(199,130,207,0.8) }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hac {
    0%, 100% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(255,81,93,0.8) }
    30% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(39,175,131,0.8) }
    70% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(199,130,207,0.8) }
}

@keyframes hac {
    0%, 100% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(255,81,93,0.8) }
    30% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(39,175,131,0.8) }
    70% { box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(199,130,207,0.8) }
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/v9t841g4/)**

Comment: thanks for your answer @Zeev Kats but i'm trying to do opacity as well, with rgba(X,X,X, 0.8 ), and with your code i can't

Comment: @ElTitoBarte Im edit my answer, take a look. its work fine with opacity

Comment: awesome code @Zeev Kats. but is not what i'm looking for, check my website and see the code and how it work in different browsers except firefox http://holicolourun.com. this code i'm trying to apply on ".header" div

Comment: You should let me see your website first, i have an idea. edit my answer now

Comment: @ElTitoBarte Edit my answer.

Comment: OMG, that is what im looking for, thanks a lot @Zeev Katz

Comment: You are GENIUS @Zeev Kats :)

Comment: Let's not exaggerate ;)

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem, css gradient animations and transitions work only on IE. Found a solution through javascript.
What it does: animates movement of gradient when page loads.

```
#topBody{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0%, ghostwhite 5%, black 5%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0%, ghostwhite 5%, black 5%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0%, ghostwhite 5%, black 5%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0%, ghostwhite 5%, black 5%);
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #696969, 0px -3px 10px #696969;
}

window.onload = function()
{
    var x = 0;
    var y = 5;
    var body = document.getElementById("topBody");
    var t = setInterval(move, 10);

    function move()
    {
        if(x==80)
        {
            clearInterval(t);
        }
        else 
        {
            x++;
            y++;
            body.style.background = "-ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, black "+x+"%, ghostwhite "+y+"%, black "+y+"%)";
            body.style.background = "-webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, black "+x+"%, ghostwhite "+y+"%, black "+y+"%)";
            body.style.background = "-moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, black "+x+"%, ghostwhite "+y+"%, black "+y+"%)";
            body.style.background = "-o-linear-gradient(-45deg, black "+x+"%, ghostwhite "+y+"%, black "+y+"%)";


        }
    }
}
```